# APEX 3.2 (Oracle): on change of an item dynamically populates the values of other items on the page

Tags: oracle-apex

I am on APEX 3.2 and in a form used to insert fields f1 and f2 in table f, I would like to have a couple of text items that will automatically populate and display based on the data typed in f1 and from a query on table t. In other word, typing empno in f1, moving to the f2 box the user should automaticcaly see emp last_name and first_name displayed. This way she can verify the empno typed was correct, type other data in f2 and submit the form.

Any suggestion on how to reach this scope?

I guess I should use some javascript.

Many thanks.
Gabriele

Comment: I saw your attempted edit on my post: better to post a comment with what is not working in brief, and if you feel you need to post some code it may be better to edit this into your original question. However, with what i gleaned from it you should probably start by using a browser which allows inspection of ajax calls. You could do this with the Firebug plugin for Firefox, or in Chrome with the dev tools. Check if an ajax call is fired. Are there any errors thrown? If not, check the response of the call and see if it indeed returns an object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 3.2 wiz, i haven't worked with it. I do know there are no dynamic actions and no page on-demand process points, so i've worked with that in mind.

Application process: 'get_emp_details'
(I don't know the processing point you can/need to choose in 3.2. If you can pick on-demand, go for it.)
Code:

```
DECLARE
   lEmp emp%rowtype;
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     INTO lEmp
     FROM emp
    WHERE empno = :P7_EMPNO;

   htp.p('{"result":"ok", "emp":{"ename":"'||lEmp.ename||'","job":"'||lEmp.job||'"}}');
EXCEPTION 
WHEN no_data_found THEN
   htp.p('{"result":"nok", "emp":{}}');
END;
```

On your page (in my case i have used page 7, change the page numbers to your page number!) put this in the html headers section (or if you have the javascript section there, put the javascript code there without the script tags):
**Edit: added in `console.log` lines. Mind that these will produce javascript errors in IE when the developer tools (F12) are not opened!**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log('document is ready');
   $("#P7_EMPNO").change(function(){
      var oDBGet = new htmldb_Get(null, $('pFlowId').val(), "APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_emp_details", '0');
      oDBGet.add('P7_EMPNO', $("#P7_EMPNO").val());
      var oResult = oDBGet.get();
      var lReturn = $.parseJSON(oResult);
      if(lReturn.result=='ok'){
         var lEmp = lReturn.emp;
         $("#P7_ENAME").val(lEmp.ename);
      } else {
         alert('ename could not be found for this empno!');
      };
   });
});
</script>
```

This will do an ajax callback when the EMPNO changes, and change the ename of the employee. Since there are no temporary application items that can be used (`apex_application.g_x##`) i'm submitting the required page item to session state. In this case `P7_EMPNO` is added to the p_arg_names array and its value in the corresponding position in the p_arg_values array. This is necessary because the session state of P7_EMPNO is used in the application process.

When inspecting the console tab in Firebug:
Post values of ajax call:
[image: AJAX call POST values]
Response values of ajax call:
[image: AJAX call RESPONSE values]

Comment: Thank you Tom for your detailed answer!

Comment: Thank you Tom for your detailed answer! I have modified your code for my situation but it is not working (probably I am making some mistakes). In my case the form is against table t while I get last_name and first_name from emp where t.badge=emp.badge (badge in place of empno). I will publish your modified code in my next answer. Please have a look. Many thanks anyway. Gabriele

Comment: Hi Tom. I use FF and have firebug. I can see the Ajax script loaded, I can't tell if it is fired or not (how can I check this?) and I don't get any error. I'll try with some alerts in the mean time. Thank you again! Gabriele

Comment: when you change the page item `P7_BADGE`. Note though, this has to be a manual change, ie you need to change the value by typing something in and then leave the item through fe tabbing out. That should trigger the ajax call.

Comment: That is exactly what I do: I type the P2_BADGE, go to another field (P2_DATE) and nothing happen in the P2_LAST_NAME.

Comment: Ok - can you see an ajax call in the console part of firebug? If not, put an alert in the change function on it. If no alert comes, then the ready function hasn't fired: put an alert in the ready function part. If it doesn't fire, it might have to do with the jquery version in apex 3.2

Comment: Running the app I can see in HTML header the loaded scripts (jquery 1.8.3-min.js, your js code, and so on...) and also in the SCRIPT console. I would say the script is fired, but I need to better check and I'll tell you. Thanks! Gabriele

Comment: Tom, I'll investigate this tomorrow, as I have an emergency!! Thank you for you help! Gabriele

Comment: Hi Tom, I have played a bit with firebug and I could see step by step your js execution until the function(data) row where, if I step into, I can see the P2_BADGE argument with its typed value. Then, the next step directly goes out of the function(data) so I would say it is not executing the code inside it. Any suggestion? Thanks, Gabriele

Comment: Gabriele: i added 2 screenshots in my post. Do you see this ajax call in firebug? If you do, check the post and response values of this call. If you have an ajax call but nothing happens, then the response is probably faulty (it should look like the response in my second screenshot). If you wonder about the other output lines in my screens: those are console.log lines, i also added them in my code snippet.

Comment: Hi Tom, I can't put images here so I will copy some text from the console in my post. I finally found an error message following your suggestions. It is not shown in error console and I saw it in ALL tab... As far as I understand the AJAX lib are included in  apex_get_3_1.js. Thanks, Gabriele.

Comment: Sorry Tom the undefined in console response was only because I forgot to change P7_EMPNO with P2_BADGE. Just to avoid misunderstandings. The rest is as I wrote before. I am going to do some trial and errors with the code inside function(data) to see if I get what cause the bad request.

Comment: Tom, for sure it was clear to you, but even emptying the code inside function(data) I get the bad request error... I guess it is the function call itself that is not well managed...?

Comment: Quite annoying, i'm sure the problem is something small :( And too bad i have no 3.2 environment. I added a small snippet in my post: htmldb_get. Could you try to run that and see what the generated result is? This is a builtin (albeit still undocumented) function of apex which also performs a call to the server, but synchronuous. Btw, you do have an application process right? Defined in the shared components? :)

Comment: Hi Tom, I do have the get_emp_details shared application process obtained modifying your sample according to my situation (you can see it in my post). Sorry for the stupid question, how/where should I run your snippet with htmldb_get? I think you are on the right way, older builtin apex functions have more probability to work in 3.2.

Comment: Oh - you can copy the code and paste it in the Console tab in Firebug. At the bottom is a single line command line, but you can expand this to multiline by pressing the upwards triangle icon on that line. Just paste the code and press run.

Comment: Response:  var ftest = function(){  var oDBGet = new htmldb...DBGet.get();  console.log(res);  };  ftest();   

POST http://oxygen:8181/apex/wwv_flow.show
 
200 OK
  237ms 
apex_get_3_1.js (line 1)
HeadersPostResponseHTMLJSONCookies

{"result":"nok", "emp":{}}

ReferenceError: res is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

console.log(res);

Comment: Shoot. I wonder where the difference would be then, but i'll not bother with that. I'll edit my code later on and remove the $.post call and replace it with htmldb_get. I don't like it and personally think $.post is cleaner, but for once i'll throw my arguments overboard.

Comment: Tom, I guess we "only" have to modify your function to use this htmldb_get request? Am I right?

Comment: Great! Thank you very much Tom! Also for modifying your code :-)

Comment: Changed it, try it out. The change is pretty straightforward too. htmldb_get is a synchronous call, so no callback is required.

Comment: Hi Tom, it works! Thank you very much for your help and patience. Not only I could integrate this check in my app I also learned a lot. Only a starting point but I know now a way to improve my small APEX applications. Best Regards, Gabriele

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you may already be going down the javascript road... I have worked with APEX 3.2 in the past on a similar problem and didn't know enough javascript to get this kind of dynamic functionality out of the platform. If you want to try an alternate method, you can tweak your user interface to provide the functionality you seek, but you'll have to check with the users if they can adapt to this style of approach, which you should be able to do using existing 3.2 functionality and no additional scripting:

**Requirements:**

Based on field inputs of field1 and field2, auto-populate an apex page with data from an existing table so that the user can confirm if the data inputted in field1 and field2 are correct. Use the data from the search results as parameters for input to a new process or form.

**Suggested Design:**

*Page 1:* start with blank page, then add three items: field1, field2 and a "submit" button.
add page process (after submit, conditional on submit button item) that redirects to Page 2 setting items P2_field1 and P2_field2 from the values on the Page 1 form.

*Page 2:* report page. set a query that will search your table of existing employees searching by partial or full string searches against the employee table. APEX 3.2 used to use the following convention to get around partial and case sensitive matching issues:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, ...
FROM table1
WHERE instr(upper(field1), upper(:P2_field1), 1, 1) > 0
  AND instr(upper(field2), upper(:P2_field2), 1, 1) > 0
```

Creating a report output "table" for a search effort helps when there may be multiple answers to the same search query... such as with common names like "Smith" or "John"...

Add an additional column to the report output or make the name column (field1 or field2) a linked column that goes to page 3 feeding the queried data from the employee table.

add the property to the column value on the report editor: redirect to "page 3", set P3_key = #KEY# where page 3 is your final target form or process and "key" is the index or primary key of the table you are searching from... or you can feed the n number of values needed already queried from the lookup table to populate the page 2 report.

I guess the important take-home is an appreciation for the limitations of older versions of Apex along with *possible* limitations with knowledge of advanced web scripting languages. Your requirements are still achievable even if all you are familiar with is the basics of your Apex version and a little SQL.

note: if your lookup table is HUGE (hundreds of thousands of records), you may need to consult your DBA for help with optimizing the table to handle the SQL search query. Adding UPPER and INSTR functions to the WHERE criteria isn't really the most efficient way to query large datasets without additional help in optimization.

Comment: Thank you Richard for this alternative idea. I am actually a DBA and I am more confident with SQL and query optimization. Problem is I don't know enough about APEX and about javascript, but this a good opportunity to start learning :-). If the js via will fail I will try with your... and probably ask you some more help ;-) Many thanks. Gabriele

Answer (score 0):

Tom,
here is your code modified to work in my system:

-- On Demand Application Process get_emp_details:

```
DECLARE
   lEmp emp%rowtype;
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     INTO lEmp
     FROM emp
    WHERE badge = :P2_BADGE;

   htp.p('{"result":"ok", "emp":{"lastname":"'||lEmp.last_name||'","firstname":"'||lEmp.first_name||'"}}');
EXCEPTION 
WHEN no_data_found THEN
   htp.p('{"result":"nok", "emp":{}}');
END;
```

-- Javascript in page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#P2_BADGE").change(function(){
      $.post('wwv_flow.show', 
             {"p_request"      : "APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_emp_details",
              "p_flow_id"      : $v('pFlowId'),
              "p_flow_step_id" : '0',
              "p_instance"     : $v('pInstance'),
              "p_arg_names"    : ['P2_BADGE'],
              "p_arg_values"   : [$('#P2_BADGE').val()]},
              function(data){
                 if(data){
                    var lReturn = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if(lReturn.result=='ok'){
                       var lEmp = lReturn.emp;
                       $("#P2_LAST_NAME").val(lEmp.last_name);
                    } else {
                       alert('ename could not be found for this empno!');
                    };
                 };
              }
      );        
   });
});
</script>
```

I am probably missing something and it doesn't display last_name in P2_LAST_NAME when I type the badge number in P2_BADGE.

Thanks,
Gabriele

Tom, here is what I have in the watch right window of firebug for the function(data) step:

```
this
  function()

arguments
[
"wwv_flow.show"
, Object { p_request=
"APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_emp_details"
,  p_flow_id=
"120"
,  p_flow_step_id=
"0"
,  more...}, function()]

0

"wwv_flow.show"

1
  Object { p_request=
"APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_emp_details"
, p_flow_id=
"120"
, p_flow_step_id=
"0"
, more...}

p_arg_names
[
"P2_BADGE"
]

p_arg_values
[
"155752"
]

p_flow_id
"120"

p_flow_step_id
"0"

p_instance
"2189517750670012"

p_request
"APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_emp_details"
2
  function()
e
"wwv_flow.show"
r
Object { p_request=
"APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_emp_details"
, p_flow_id=
"120"
, p_flow_step_id=
"0"
, more...}
p_arg_names
[
"P2_BADGE"
]
p_arg_values
[
"155752"
]

p_flow_id
"120"
p_flow_step_id
"0"
p_instance
"2189517750670012"
p_request
"APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_emp_details"
s
undefined
i
function()
toString
  function()

Closure Scope
  Closure Scope { toString=function()}
Closure Scope
  Closure Scope { toString=function()}
Window
  Window f?p=120:2:2189517750670012::NO:::
```

---

From my firebug 1.10.6 console:

document is ready

f?p=12...::NO::: (line 29)

empno has changed

f?p=12...::NO::: (line 31)

performing a post with empno value: undefined

f?p=12...::NO::: (line 32)

POST

400 Bad Request
        48ms
wwv_fl....min.js (line 2)
HeadersPostResponseHTMLCookies

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY><H1>Bad Request</H1>
The HTTP client sent a request that this server could not understand.</BODY></HTML>
```

-- And the post tab:

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
p_arg_names[]   P2_BADGE
p_arg_values[]  155751
p_flow_id   120
p_flow_step_id  0
p_instance  4466366911674565
p_request   APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_emp_details
Source
p_request=APPLICATION_PROCESS%3Dget_emp_details&p_flow_id=120&p_flow_step_id=0&p_instance=4466366911674565&p_arg_names%5B%5D=P2_BADGE&p_arg_values%5B%5D=155751
```

Comment: Gabriele, see my comment on your question. We need to find where exactly you get stuck. It would be best to be able to inspect ajax calls. Hopefully you have a browser available to do that (for example, you can't with IE8). If you don't then the code should get littered with javascript alerts: one in the change function body, and some in the success function of the ajax call.

Comment: Sorry Tom, I am new to stackoverflow and I am not using it properly... I apologize. I use FF and have firebug. I can see the Ajax script loaded, I can't tell if it is fired or not (how can I check this?) and I don't get any error. I'll try with some alerts in the mean time. Thank you again! Gabriele