# Dynamic validation in apex 3.2

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have different fields in APEX 3.2, the margin is calculated depending on the values entered by the user. How to do a validation of Margin ? Ex Suppose the  margin is less than zero ,User should get an alert popup on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Also see this question: [APEX 3.2 (Oracle): on change of an item dynamically populates the values of other items on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648314/apex-3-2-oracle-on-change-of-an-item-dynamically-populates-the-values-of-othe)
I'm not a 3.2 wizard but i'll try to help out.

Create an application process called 'calculate_margin'

```
DECLARE
   lMargin NUMBER;
BEGIN
   lMargin := :P8_ITEM1 + :P8_ITEM2 + :P8_ITEM3;

   IF lMargin < 0 THEN
      htp.p('{"result":"nok", "message":"margin is less than zero!"}');
   ELSE
      htp.p('{"result":"ok", "message":"margin is ok"}');
   END IF;      
END;
```

Put this javascript code on your page. If you have no javascript section, put this between `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags.

```
function checkMargin(){
   $.post('wwv_flow.show', 
          {"p_request"      : "APPLICATION_PROCESS=calculate_margin",
           "p_flow_id"      : $v('pFlowId'),
           "p_flow_step_id" : '0',
           "p_instance"     : $v('pInstance'),
           "p_arg_names"    : ['P8_ITEM1','P8_ITEM2','P8_ITEM3'],
           "p_arg_values"   : [$('#P8_ITEM1').val(),$('#P8_ITEM2').val(),$('#P8_ITEM3').val()]},
           function(data){
              if(data){
                 var lReturn = $.parseJSON(data);
                 if(lReturn.result=='ok'){
                    //you could do something here 
                 } else {
                    alert(lReturn.message);
                 };
              };
           }
   );
};
```

Now on to the button. If this is a button you defined in apex, change it to point to a URL, and in the URL, put this:

```
javascript:checkMargin();
```